# How to check if a word has vector representaion in spacy and does List expression in python has 'if, if else' format

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, list-comprehension, spacy

I am doing an NLP project where in I am trying to find similar items between two lists. Before making the similarity comparison I want to check if there exists a vector form of the particular word.

I have the below code written after going through the spacy documentation.

```
import en_vectors_web_lg
nlp = en_vectors_web_lg.load()
mylist_x =['crank', 'spindle', '403 (b)','education']
mylist_y = ['engine','Blockchain','data','husk'] 
newlist=[]
for token1 in mylist_x:
    list_to_sort = [(token1, token2, nlp(str(token1)).similarity(nlp(str(token2)))) for token2 in mylist_y if doc.vocab [token1].has_vector if doc.vocab [token2].has_vector else newlist.append['no match']]
    sorted_list = sorted(list_to_sort, key = itemgetter(2), reverse=True)[:1]
    print("here is the sorted_list", sorted_list)
```

My question is two fold:

First: Am i doing the 'if if else' part correctly in the list comprehension correctly? Is it possible to do 'if if else' in list comprehension ?

Second: Am i invoking doc.vocab part correctly to check whether the word has vectors.

Looking for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That comprehension is too long, I suggest to split it in more for cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `has_vector` to check if a token has a vector( it will return a boolean value):

```
tokens = nlp("dog cat mouse")

for token in tokens:
    print(token.has_vector)
```